# Pressed property stays false after keypress

Tags: c#, winforms, menuitem, menubar, menustrip

I'm creating a custom renderer for the MenuStrip control. In the renderer class, I am checking the pressed property of the particular menu item (menuStrip.Item.Pressed) to check if the user has clicked the menuitem, so that I can change my rendering style accordingly. This works fine until you try to use the keyboard to navigate the menu. After doing that, the pressed property stays false for all items that were navigated to with the keyboard. The ones that the keyboard hasn't touched still work when clicked with the mouse. I know I could probably create a workaround with a clicked event handler and setting a bool value, but why should I have to when it seems this pressed property is designed specifically for this purpose. Is this a bug in .NET or am I doing something wrong?

```
private class myRenderer : ToolStripProfessionalRenderer
{
    protected override void OnRenderMenuItemBackground(ToolStripItemRenderEventArgs myMenu)
    {
        if (!myMenu.Item.Selected)
            base.OnRenderMenuItemBackground(myMenu);
        if (myMenu.Item.Pressed)
        {
            //If it is a base menu and the menu is open, then dont't draw it
            if (myMenu.Item.OwnerItem == null)
                base.OnRenderMenuItemBackground(myMenu);
            else
            {
                //When click on sub menuitem
                LinearGradientBrush brush = new LinearGradientBrush(Point.Empty, new Point(0, myMenu.Item.Height), Color.FromArgb(190, 230, 245), Color.White);
                Rectangle menuRectangle = new Rectangle(Point.Empty, myMenu.Item.Size);
                menuRectangle.X += 2;
                menuRectangle.Width -= 2;
                //Fill Color
                myMenu.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, menuRectangle);
                //Border Color
                Pen pen = new Pen(Brushes.AliceBlue, 1);
                pen.Color = Color.FromArgb(125, 162, 206);
                myMenu.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, 2, 0, menuRectangle.Width - 2, menuRectangle.Height - 1);
                myMenu.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.White, new Point(4, menuRectangle.Height - 2), new Point(menuRectangle.Width - 1, menuRectangle.Height - 2));
            }
        }
        else if (myMenu.Item.Selected)
        {
            if (myMenu.Item.OwnerItem == null)
            {
                //When hover over main menuitem
                LinearGradientBrush brush = new LinearGradientBrush(Point.Empty, new Point(0, myMenu.Item.Height), Color.White, Color.FromArgb(190, 230, 245));
                Rectangle menuRectangle = new Rectangle(Point.Empty, myMenu.Item.Size);
                //Fill Color
                myMenu.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, menuRectangle);
                //Border Color
                Pen pen = new Pen(Brushes.AliceBlue, 1);
                pen.Color = Color.FromArgb(125, 162, 206);
                myMenu.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, 0, 0, menuRectangle.Width - 1, menuRectangle.Height - 1);
                myMenu.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.White, new Point(1, menuRectangle.Height - 2), new Point(menuRectangle.Width - 2, menuRectangle.Height - 2));
            }
            else
            {
                //When hover over sub menuitem
                LinearGradientBrush brush = new LinearGradientBrush(Point.Empty, new Point(0, myMenu.Item.Height), Color.White, Color.FromArgb(190, 230, 245));
                Rectangle menuRectangle = new Rectangle(Point.Empty, myMenu.Item.Size);
                menuRectangle.X += 2;
                menuRectangle.Width -= 2;
                //Fill Color
                myMenu.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, menuRectangle);
                //Border Color
                Pen pen = new Pen(Brushes.AliceBlue, 1);
                pen.Color = Color.FromArgb(125, 162, 206);
                myMenu.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, 2, 0, menuRectangle.Width - 2, menuRectangle.Height - 1);
                myMenu.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.White, new Point(4, menuRectangle.Height - 2), new Point(menuRectangle.Width - 1, menuRectangle.Height - 2));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Kinda hard to debug without seeing some code.

Comment: No repro, .NET 3.5 and 4.5.1.  Didn't expect one, a renderer doesn't mess up the state of a menuitem of course.

Comment: Just tested 3.5. Still happens.